# Is it enough for methods to be distinguished just by argument name (not type)?

Tags: c#, naming, coding-standards, conventions, method-overloading

Is it enough for methods to be distinguished just by argument name (not type) or is it better to name it more explicitly?

For example `T Find<T>(int id)` vs `T FindById<T>(int id)`.

Is there any good reason to name it more explicitly (i.e. adding `ById`) vs keeping just argument name?

One reason I can think of is when signatures of the methods are the same but they have a different meaning.

`FindByFirstName(string name)` and `FindByLastName(string name)`

Comment: So when you overload Find to include `T Find<T>(string name)` or `(int size)` how do you plan to resolve the inevitable problems?

Comment: @UKMonkey what inevitable problems?

Comment: in the first case: if multiple entries have the same name then you would have to change the function signature; which means people will likely get confused with what it's meant to return;  In the latter case, the argument is the same - and thus an illegal overload.  You either start naming the function with "byX" or make an object for the argument so that you can have the equivalent of overload with same argument.  Either works well for different situations.

Comment: @UKMonkey you can post an answer with some code examples if you want

Comment: Ids should probably be an opaque `ID` object and not just an `int`. In that way get compile-time checking that you do not use an id for an int or viceversa in some part of your code. And with that you can have `find(int value)` and `find(ID id)`.

Comment: In that case, it may be beneficial to have a generic `T find<T, U>(U key, KeyType kt)`, where `KeyType` is an enum indicating whether the key is, e.g., an `id` or a `firstName` or a `size` or whatever.  It would delegate to the appropriate searcher, giving the simplicity of `Find()` but the benefits of the full name.  [Note that I'm not entirely familiar with how C# generics work, so there may be a mistake in there.]

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Sure there is a good reason to name it more explicitly.

It's not primarily be the method *definition* that should be self-explanatory, but the method *use*. And while `findById(string id)` and `find(string id)` are both self-explanatory, there is a huge difference between `findById("BOB")` and `find("BOB")`. In the former case you know that the random literal is, in fact, an Id. In the latter case you're not sure - it might actually be a given name or something else entirely.

Comment: Except in the 99% of other cases where you have a variable or property name is a point of reference: `findById(id)` vs `find(id)`. You can go either way on this.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: A particular value is not necessarily named the same way for a method and its caller. For example, consider `double Divide(int numerator, int denominator)` being used in a method: `double murdersPerCapita = Divide(murderCount, citizenCount)`. You can't rely on two methods using the same variable name as there are plenty of cases where that is not the case (or when it is the case, it's bad naming)

Comment: @Flater: Given the code in the question (finding stuff from some sort of persistent storage) I imagine you might call this method with a "murderedCitizenId" or "citizenId" ... I really don't think the argument or variable names are ambiguous here. And honestly I could go either way on this. It's actually a very opinionated question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: You cannot distill a global rule from a single example. OP's question is _in general_, not specific to the example given. Yes, there are some cases where using the same name makes sense, but there are also cases where it doesn't. Hence this answer,, it's best to aim for **consistency** even if it's not _necessary_ in a subset of use cases.

Comment: Named parameters resolve the confusion in your example. Do you have an example where named parameters would not help?

Comment: Names parameters resolve the confusion *after the confusion has already existed*, as you need to look at the method definition, while explicitly named methods entirely *avoid the confusion* by having the name present in the method call. Also, you can't have two methods with the same name and argument type but different argument name, which means you're going to need explicit names in certain cases anyway.

Comment: Rather than lumping the arg description into the method name, you can also use a [named argument](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Comment: findByUserId & findByUserFirstName would be even better

Comment: Just adding a note that if you use Jetbrains IDE/extension you have a feature called "inlay hints" https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Options__Environment__Parameter_Name_Hints.html which shows parameter name before value.

Answer (score 35):

**Advantages of FindById()**.

1. **Future-proofing**: If you start with `Find(int)`, and later have to add other methods (`FindByName(string)`, `FindByLegacyId(int)`, `FindByCustomerId(int)`, `FindByOrderId(int)`, etc), people like me tend to spend ages looking for  `FindById(int)`. Not really a problem *if* you can and will change `Find(int)` to `FindById(int)` once it becomes necessary - future proofing is about these *if*s.
2. **Easier to read**. `Find` is perfectly fine if the call looks like `record = Find(customerId);` Yet `FindById` is slightly easier for reading if it's `record = FindById(AFunction());`.
3. **Consistency**. You can consistently apply the `FindByX(int)` / `FindByY(int)` pattern everywhere, but `Find(int X)` / `Find(int Y)` is not possible because they conflict.

**Advantages of Find()**

- KISS. `Find` is simple and straightforward, and alongside `operator[]` it's one of the 2 most expected function names in this context. (Some popular alternatives being [`get`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/182113/how-and-why-to-decide-between-naming-methods-with-get-and-find-prefixes), `lookup`, or `fetch`, depending on context).
- As a rule of thumb, if you have a function name that is a single well-known word which accurately describes what the function does, use it. Even if there is a longer multi-word name that is slightly better at describing what the function does. Example: [Length](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netframework-4.7.2) vs [NumberOfElements](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/numberofelements.html). There is a tradeoff, and where to draw the line is subject of an ongoing debate.
- It's generally good to avoid redundancy. If we look at `FindById(int id)`, we can easily remove redundancy by changing it to `Find(int id)`, but there is a trade off - we lose some clarity.

---

Alternatively you can **get the advantages of both** by using strongly typed Ids:

```
CustomerRecord Find(Id<Customer> id) 
// Or, depending on local coding standards
CustomerRecord Find(CustomerId id)
```

Implementation of `Id<>`: [Strongly typing ID values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377237/strongly-typing-id-values-in-c-sharp)

Comments here, as well as in the link above, raised multiple concerns regarding `Id<Customer>` that I would like to address:

- **Concern 1: It's an abuse of generics.** `CustomerId` and `OrderID` are different types (`customerId1 = customerId2;` => good, `customerId1 = orderId1;` => bad), but their implementation is nearly identical, so we can implement them either with copy paste or with metaprogramming. While there is value in a discussion about either exposing or hiding the generic, metaprogramming is what generics are for.
- **Concern 2: It doesn't stop simple mistakes./It's a solution in search of a problem** The main issue that's removed by using strongly typed Ids is the wrong argument order in a call to `DoSomething(int customerId, int orderId, int productId)`. Strongly typed Ids also prevent other problems, including the one OP asked about.
- **Concern 3: It really just obscures code.** It's hard to tell if an id is held in `int aVariable`. It's easy to tell that an Id is held in `Id<Customer> aVariable`, and we can even tell that it's a customer Id.
- **Concern 4: These Ids are no strong types, just wrappers.** `String` is just a wrapper around `byte[]`. Wrapping, or encapsulation, is not in conflict with strong typing.
- **Concern 5: It's over engineered.** Here's the minimal version, although I do recommend adding `operator==` and `operator!=` as well, if you don't want to rely exclusively on `Equals`:

.

```
public struct Id<T>: {
    private readonly int _value ;
    public Id(int value) { _value = value; }
    public static explicit operator int(Id<T> id) { return id._value; }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Another way of thinking about this is to use the type safety of the language.

You can implement a method such as:

```
Find(FirstName name);
```

Where FirstName is a simple object that wraps a string which contains the first name and means there can be no confusion as to what the method is doing, nor in the arguments with which it is called.

Comment: Not sure what your answer is to the OPs question. Do you recommend to use a name like "Find" by relying on the type of the argument? Or do you recommend to use such names only when there is an explicit type for the argument(s), and use a more explicit  name like "FindById" elsewhere? Or do you recommend to introduce explicit types to make a name like "Find" more feasible?

Comment: @DocBrown I think the latter, and I like it. It's actually similar to Peter's answer, iiuc. The rationale as I understand it is two-fold: (1) It's clear from the argument type what the function does; (2) You cannot make mistakes like `string name = "Smith"; findById(name);`.which is possible if you use non-descript general types.

Comment: While in general I am a fan of compile time type safety, be careful with wrapper types. Introducing wrapper classes for the sake of type safety can at times severely complicate your API if done in excess. e.g., the whole "artist formerly known as int" problem that winapi has; in the long run I would say most people just look at the endless `DWORD` `LPCSTR` etc. clones and think "it's an int / string / etc.", it gets to the point where you spend more time propping up your tools than you do actually designing code.

Comment: @jrh True. My litmus test for introducing "nominal" types (differing only in name) is when common functions/methods don't make any sense in our use case, e.g. `int`s are often summed, multiplied, etc. which is meaningless for IDs; so I'd make `ID` distinct from `int`. This can simplify an API, by narrowing down what we can do given a value (e.g. if we have an `ID`, it will only work with `find`, not e.g. `age` or `highscore`). Conversely, if we find ourselves converting a lot, or writing the same function/method (e.g. `find`) for multiple types, that's a sign that our distinctions are too fine

Answer (score 1):

I will vote for explicit declaration like FindByID.... 
Software should be built for Change. It should be open and closed (SOLID). So the class is open to add similar find method like let's say FindByName.. etc.

But FindByID is closed and its implementation is unit tested.

I won't suggest methods with predicates, those are good at generic level. What if based on the field(ByID) you have complete different methodology.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised no one suggested to use a predicate such as the following:

```
User Find(Predicate<User> predicate)
```

With this approach not only you reduce the surface of your API but also give more control to the user using it.

If that isn't enough you can always expand it to your needs.

Comment: The problem is that it's less efficient due to the fact that it can't take advantage of things such as indices.